# Ubuntu Touch for Nexus 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am trying to get Ubuntu Touch for my Nexus 5, but when I enter the command:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel="ubuntu-touch/devel" --bootstrap --server="http://system-image.tasemnice.eu"
```

I get:

```
phablet-device-flash: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check here:(this is from the [Installing Ubuntu on Nexus Guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/))

Firstly have you enabled your nexus into developer mode and enabled USB debugging.

After enabling Developer Mode, the Developer options item is exposed in the Settings page.

Navigate to Settings → Developer options
Enable USB Debugging. When a device is connected, you will be prompted in Android to authorize it.

3. Physically connect your enabled device to your Ubuntu Desktop over USB.
4. On Android, accept the prompt to Allow USB debugging for the specified computer.
5. To verify the connection, use adb to display currently connected devices:

Then in the terminal:

$ adb devices

This should show your device

Secondly you need to remember to restart your device into the bootloader mode again in the terminal:

*adb reboot bootloader*

Then rerun the ubuntu-device-flash --  command that you did earlier

I really recommend re reading the wiki guide though to ensure that you are following the right methodology

I would also recommend that you read the new guide and tool developed by Marius Quabeck which is much much easier:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/new-tool-lets-you-easily-install-ubuntu-touch-os-on-your-devices-with-dual-boot-509386.shtml

Comment: I have an update. I have used Marius Quabek's Magic Device Tool to install really  good version of Ubuntu. It is very easy to use and Marius has put in so much effort to make it work. You can use it to install Ubuntu or many other OS. Here is the link: https://github.com/MariusQuabeck/magic-device-tool